# iphone clipping a MyPicker : pickerview : uiview

Tags: iphone, ios4, uipickerview, clipping, cgpath

Just checking to see if someone has done this before.

I used to have ways to modify the size of a UIPickerView. But it seems that ever since iOS4.0 it seems to be locked. If I do the usual trickery and compile targeting 3.0 it works as usual. But this is for a free app with iAd so it's going to be an iOS4 only affair.

So I'm thinking on sub-classing a pickerview (as MyPciker). Since UIPickerView  inherits from UIView, could I clip it at -drawRect with a CGPath? All I need for my picker is to show just three rows, which at 50px each would return a picker with 150px in height.

Just wondering if someone has tried this one before as I'm about to get my coding session on ;)

Regards and thanks in advance,
david